# hexdump in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, hexdump

I want to see the dump of my `sqlite` `.db` file inside my Xcode project like on a `UILableView`.

How can I run a command line command like `hexdump` from within my iOS app?

Comment: What good is a hex dump?

Comment: Viewing it via the simulator version on disk isn't sufficient?

Comment: @trojanfoe It's a hexadecimal... well... *dump* of a file.

Comment: The question is rather "what good is an `UILableView`?"

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah cheers, I know *what* it is, but I asked what *good* it would be.

Comment: @OP: The language is called "Objective-C". And this is completely unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: This is for a proof of concept to demonstrate for other technically not sophisticated group

Comment: If you are running on the simulator you can locate your DB file inside the simulated phone directory structure and use the `sqlite3` OSx command inside a command entry window to access the DB in symbolic form -- display table definitions, dump contents, even run queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I run a command line command like hexdump from within my iOS app?

On MacOS X, you could do this using `NSTask` to run whatever program you want. You'd use `NSPipe` to send data to and/or get data from the command.

But you can't do that on iOS. First of all, the `hexdump` command may or may not exist in a standard iOS installation. Second, `NSTask` isn't available. If you really just want to dump the bytes from a file into a label, it's not difficult. I'd look at using `NSInputStream` to open the file and read its data, and then convert each byte to an appropriate hex string and add that to a larger string that'll accumulate the total dump. Once you're done, assign that larger string as the text of the label. Or, you could do the same thing yourself by just reading the file into an instance of `NSData` and iterate over the `bytes` yourself to produce the hex string.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to read the file as raw data, then display the bytes however you want (for example, using a [format string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:)).

-actually from another user @[jtbandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23649/jtbandes)